# What features in NMS require an online connection to work outisde those directly tied to multiplayer?

Tags: no-mans-sky

No Man's Sky is first and foremost a single player game.
Playing in "online mode" grants the ability to play "multiplayer" but at the same time connects the game to the global online Discovery server. This means that the game will start displaying other players discoveries in the game. Many players don't want this, especially when there is plenty of planets/flora/fauna that some smart guys have named with vulgar or racist words...

Since the game isn't based around the multiplayer features, everything works the same while in single player. But as you play you notice that apparently Hello Games tied some specific things  in the game that have nothing to do with multiplayer to the availability of their online servers.

This is obviously pure nonsense: not only it fells kinda toxic for those who couldn't care less about multiplayer features, it also means that ***when*** the online servers will inevitably shut down those features will be broken **forever**.

Currently, I have noticed the following features requiring online mode:

- daily price reset for Emergency Broadcaster: normally the price increase with every bought receiver but reset back to 5M every day. While playing offline this does not happen and the price keeps increasing until the cost of the receiver is far greater than anything you can gain from it.
- Iteration Helios:  does not work offline (he won't trade nor give the weekly free broadcaster). Oddly Iteration Ares (another NPC that shares similar gimmiks) seems to work just fine.
- Quicksilver Vendor: some player report not being able to see some of the available items for purchase while offline.
- Expeditions: expeditions appear as "available" for starting only while online (both in the new game menu and at the Anomaly terminal added in the Omega update). Once started, the expedition can be played offline (minus any online only "community goal").

Since some of this features have been changed over multiple patches I am wondering if anyone has a complete lists of every feature that actually requires an online connection to work as expected despite the game making no mention of it.